# Is it possible to build a basic text based shell/command line ontop of freebsd kernel?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, freebsd

I am interested in operating system development and have a basic knowledge of c, c++, and java. I would like to program a custom text based shell/command line that runs on top of the FreeBSD kernel.

My question is how would I go about obtaining the kernel and writing my custom environment into it, and what tools and resources would I need.

Btw. I am also open to linux, I just prefer the BSD License.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is unanswerable because it is too broad. Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial service. Stack Overflow ist best for questions on specific problems.

Comment: Writing a shell is hardly related to OS development. You can write a perfectly good and portable shell in C/C++/Java, regardless of the OS or kernel. And the FreeBSD kernel source [appears to be on GitHub](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd), you should have been able to find it yourself had you searched.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with that github link, that helps alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Shell is just an ordinary program, like any other.  It doesn't use any special APIs.  So, you can just install FreeBSD, write the software you would like to become the shell, and just set it up as user's shell, by using chsh command.

Comment: Thank you, what would happen later in the future if I wanted to write a graphical shell?

Comment: Pretty much the same, except that you would need to set it up to be started by Xorg after user login, eg using the ~/.xinitrc file.

Comment: I sorta meant though like what If I didn't want to use X11 instead using Wayland? Thank you though.

Comment: Then you will find some other way to run it :-)

Sorry, I know nothing about Wayland.  But it has to have some way to run a user-chosen binary as a shell.